# Prove that when x approaches to 1, function 1/(x-1) doesn't have limit

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1} $ does not exist.

Proof

The definition for limit doesn't exist is

$\forall L\in \mathbb R,\exists \epsilon>0 ,\forall \delta>0 ,\exists x\in domf$ such that $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|\frac{1}{x-1}-L|\geq \epsilon$

Chose $x=\frac{1}{n}+1>0,n\in \mathbb N$. Then based on Archimedean property $|x-1|=|\frac{1}{n}+1-1|=\frac{1}{n}<\delta$

Also $|\frac{1}{x-1}-L|\geq \epsilon$ means that $\frac{1}{x-1}\geq L+\epsilon$ or $\frac{1}{x-1}\leq L-\epsilon$

Because $x=\frac{1}{n}+1>0$, $\frac{1}{x-1}=n$. Also based on Archimedean property, there exists a natural number such that it is greater than $L+\epsilon$

Then choose $epsilon$ to be any positive numbers.

Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1} $ does not exist.

Is this correct? Also, I'm kind of confused about the quantifiers in the limit statement.

In the sentence "$\forall L\in \mathbb R,\exists \epsilon>0,\forall \delta>0,\exists x\in domf$, does this mean that there exists a constant epsilon, just like "1,2,...".Then this fixed constant should satisfy all delta. And for every delta, there is a $x$. In the end, epsilon is kind of “isolated”，but x is "accompanying" with the delta.

Comment: A minor mistake: it should be $0<|x-1|<\delta$. Otherwise, this is OK but it's what you write in your scratchwork. In the actual proof, the order of your statements should correspond to the definition you wrote read from left to right, i.e. you start with $L$, then $\varepsilon$, and so on. Also, be explicit when you're choosing something. How exactly is $n$ chosen?

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, and I want to confirm that the epsilon actually can't depend on anything right? It is just a number.

Comment: it could only depend on $L$. But things here are simple enough that you could just say "let $\varepsilon=1$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the right ingredients and all the right tools, but I can see from your write-up alone that you are finding the four nested quantifiers difficult. And it is difficult to properly wrap your head around. It might help if you start with a skeleton for your proof, that you can fill in.

Because your statement starts with $\forall L \in \Bbb{R}$, a good sentence to begin your proof would be

> Suppose $L \in \Bbb{R}$.

The next quantifier is $\exists \varepsilon > 0$. So, at some point after this first sentence, we will need

> Let $\varepsilon = \underline{\hspace{20pt}}$ [a function of $L$, taking into account the definition of the function $f$].

The specific value for this $\varepsilon$ is for us to decide. This should be based on our scratch work. The next quantifier is $\forall \delta > 0$, so once again, we will need the following:

> Suppose $\delta \in \Bbb{R}$.

Based on our final quantifier, we then want:

> Let $x = \underline{\hspace{20pt}}$ [a function of $L$ and $\delta$, taking into account $f$ and possibly our choice of $\varepsilon$].

That's when we can start proving the predicate at the end of the quantifiers: that $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$, that $|x - 1| < \delta$, and that $|\frac{1}{x - 1} - L| \ge \varepsilon$.

Now, let's fill in the gaps. From your proof, $\varepsilon > 0$ seemed to be arbitrary. All you needed was some $n \ge L + \varepsilon$. So, let's just pick $\varepsilon = 1$. And why not! You should be able to find some $n \ge L + 1$.

Next, we need to figure out our $x$. You chose $x = \frac{1}{n} + 1$, which is potentially sensible, but you should really define your $n$ first. How was $n$ defined in your proof? It was defined to satisfy two properties:

1. $n \ge L + \varepsilon = L + 1$, and
2. $\frac{1}{n} < \delta$.

Both of these are sensible conditions based on the Archimedean principle. Let's define:
$$n = \max\left\{\lceil L \rceil + 1, \left\lceil \frac{1}{\delta}\right\rceil + 1\right\},$$
where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the ceiling function (which only exists due to the Archimedean property!). Then, it makes sense to define $x = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$. With this in mind, I would write the proof as follows:

> Suppose $L \in \Bbb{R}$. Let $\varepsilon = 1$, and suppose $\delta \in \Bbb{R}$. Define
> $$n = \max\left\{\lceil L \rceil + 1, \left\lceil \frac{1}{\delta}\right\rceil + 1\right\} \in \Bbb{N}.$$
> Then $n \ge \left\lceil\frac{1}{\delta}\right\rceil + 1 > \frac{1}{\delta} \implies \delta < \frac{1}{n}$. Further, $n \ge \lceil L \rceil + 1 \ge L + 1 = L + \varepsilon$.
>
> Let $x = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$. Note that $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \{1\} = \operatorname{dom} f$. Then,
> $$|x - 1| = \frac{1}{n} < \delta,$$
> and
> $$|f(x) - L| = \left|\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n} + 1 - 1} - L\right| = |n - L| \ge n - L \ge 1 = \varepsilon.$$
> Therefore,
> $$\forall L \in \Bbb{R}, \exists \varepsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0, \exists x \in \operatorname{dom} f \text{ such that } |x - 1| < \delta \text{ and } |f(x) - L| \ge \varepsilon.$$